# ODE-separation of variables proof

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Let's assume an ODE of the type $$y'=g(x)h(y(x)),$$
where $g:I\to\mathbb{R}$, $h:J\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions and ${\xi\choose\eta}\in I\times J$.

In the case of $h(\eta)=0$ the solution is clear. So let's assume $h(\eta)\neq 0$. Then, we know that by solving the equation:

$$
\int_{\eta}^y\frac{1}{h(s)}ds=\int_{\xi}^xg(t)dt
$$
with respect to $y$ delivers a solution of the ODE.

---

In our lecture the professor has proven this statement by constructing another function, namely

$$H(u):=\int_{\eta}^u\frac{1}{h(s)}ds$$
and then showing its invertibility. After some additional steps he finally comes to the conclusion that
$$y:=H^{-1}\left(\int_{\xi}^xg(t)dt\right)$$
is a (unique) solution of the ODE.

In the literature this seems a standard way of proving the theorem. However, I was wondering why we cannot simply say that in the case of $h(\eta)\neq 0$ it directly follows from the implicit function theorem?

---

**EDIT:**

Some more details regarding the implicit function theorem:

Let be $y(\xi)=\eta$ and $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, where
$$
F(x,y)=\int_{\eta}^y\frac{1}{h(s)}ds-\int_{\xi}^xg(t)dt.
$$
Now we look at $F(x,y)\overset{!}{=}0$ and see that $F(\xi,y(\xi))=0$. All assumptions of the implicit function theorem are satisfied (I have skipped the details), so we know there exists a function $f$ such that $F(x,f(x))=0$. Further, we know how the derivative of $f$ looks like, namely $f'(x)= (-1) \left(\left(\int_{\eta}^{f(x)}\frac{1}{h(s)}ds\right)'\right)^{-1}\left(-\int_{\xi}^xg(t)dt\right)'=f(x) h(f(x)).$

Hence, the implicit function $f$ is a solution of the ODE.
(I know this is a bit sloppy but I hope it explains the main idea)

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid, but I don't see what the implicit function theorem has to do with this. Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: @HansLundmark, please see my edit :)

Comment: @Hans, it seems to me that using the implicit function theorem and inverting H are essentially the same thing. The implicit function theorem is proven using the inverse function theorem after all, right? You always need the same hypothesis in this case proceeding in both ways, that is, $H’(\eta)\neq 0$.